# Solve complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Pls help me to solve this equation on photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eajr3.png)

Comment: (z+1)^n+(z-1)^n=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
As $z=1$ is not a solution of
$$(z+1)^n+(z-1)^n=0$$
you can reewrite the equation as
$$\biggl(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\biggr)^{\!n}=-1=\mathrm e^{i\pi}$$
Solve for $u^n=-1$ first, then express $z$ in function of $u$.